# How to set the rules in outlook profile

Tags: c#, outlook, profile, rules

I have got all outlook profile rules from Store.GetRules method (Outlook), Now how can I set that all the rules in other profile

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Rules.Create](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.rules.create) method which creates a `Rule` object with the name specified by `Name` and the type of rule specified by `RuleType`.

```
Sub CreateRule()  
 Dim colRules As Outlook.Rules  
 Dim oRule As Outlook.Rule  
 Dim colRuleActions As Outlook.RuleActions  
 Dim oMoveRuleAction As Outlook.MoveOrCopyRuleAction  
 Dim oFromCondition As Outlook.ToOrFromRuleCondition  
 Dim oExceptSubject As Outlook.TextRuleCondition  
 Dim oInbox As Outlook.Folder  
 Dim oMoveTarget As Outlook.Folder 

 'Specify target folder for rule move action  
 Set oInbox = Application.Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)  
 'Assume that target folder already exists  
 Set oMoveTarget = oInbox.Folders("Eugene")  

 'Get Rules from Session.DefaultStore object  
 Set colRules = Application.Session.DefaultStore.GetRules()  

 'Create the rule by adding a Receive Rule to Rules collection  
 Set oRule = colRules.Create("Eugene's rule", olRuleReceive) 

 'Specify the condition in a ToOrFromRuleCondition object  
 'Condition is if the message is sent by "Eugene"  
 Set oFromCondition = oRule.Conditions.From  
 With oFromCondition  
 .Enabled = True  
 .Recipients.Add ("Eugene")  
 .Recipients.ResolveAll  
 End With 

 'Specify the action in a MoveOrCopyRuleAction object  
 'Action is to move the message to the target folder  
 Set oMoveRuleAction = oRule.Actions.MoveToFolder  
 With oMoveRuleAction  
 .Enabled = True  
 .Folder = oMoveTarget  
 End With  

 'Specify the exception condition for the subject in a TextRuleCondition object  
 'Exception condition is if the subject contains "fun" or "chat"  
 Set oExceptSubject = _  
 oRule.Exceptions.Subject  
 With oExceptSubject  
 .Enabled = True  
 .Text = Array("fun", "chat")  
 End With 

  'Update the server and display progress dialog  
  colRules.Save  
End Sub
```

Comment: I don't want to create the rules I got all the rules using                                                       
var session1 = sourceAccInfo.Session;
Outlook._Stores stores = session1.Stores;
var SourceRules = session1.Stores.Application.Session.DefaultStore.GetRules();         
Now I just copy this rules in other profile